# How to change background color of only selected item on a ListView

Tags: android, listview

I am using this code

```
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parentView, View view, int position, long id) {

            selectid = position;

            for (int j = 0; j < parentView.getChildCount(); j++)
                parentView.getChildAt(j).setBackgroundResource(R.color.listitem_normal);

            // change the background color of the selected element
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.color.listitem_pressed);

        }
    });
```

but if a lot of items, if I select an item and start flipping down I see it selected and other items about every 5. If all items are placed on the screen (no need to scroll) while all OK.

Could you explain how to fix it? I have tried many options.

Comment: Try my code. May be that will help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can keep track the position of the current selected element:

```
OnItemClickListener listViewOnItemClick = new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapter, View arg1, int position, long id) {
            mSelectedItem = position;
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

And override the getView method of your adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.item_list, null);

    if (position == mSelectedItem) {
        // set your color
    }

    return view;
}
```

Comment: I did as it is written, now I just select the first item is, I can not select other